# Has anyone saved the hats for 2017?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The hats go back in the box in a few days, but as they say, "The Internet is Forever."

In previous years, people have made backups of the hats in their original SVG files (not just screencaps). Has anyone done this for this years hats?

Answer (score 16):

I've done the hard work again this year and created [a GitHub repository with every known Winter Bash 2017 hat](https://github.com/unikong/winterbash-2017-hats).

Each hat is available in their original SVG format, and a PNG convert. The common ones were extracted from the CSS stylesheet data URI's, and the secret hats were downloaded from their secret URL's.

Incidentally, no need to save separate outline files this year, as they were created with CSS filters.

```
.wb-hatimg-stroke {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: contrast(0%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(202deg) saturate(80%) drop-shadow(0px 0 1px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0 0 #fff) drop-shadow(0px 0 0 #fff);
}
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that these hats technically belong Stack Exchange, and their license is currently unknown, though it has been permissive in previous  years.

Comment: Thanks for this - I have always saved the screen grab, which has issues, obviously.

Comment: Thank you so much, +15 rep from me. I seem to be having an issue with many of the SVGs, though. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li6tG.jpg), many are just a black silhouette. Maybe just one layer made it during download.

Comment: @BigBadCat They all work fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Alex I downloaded them from Github, possibly the SVGs got a little messed up during download. The pic is in file manager, but they are the same in Gimp.

Comment: @BigBadCat In my experience, some SVG renderers have trouble with some SVG files. I've had the same problem as you with imagemagick (which probably uses the same library as Gimp) and had to use a headless browser to render the PNG files alongside the SVG files. If you open them in a browser, they would probably look right.